# reference to 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/' requires an API version

Tags: azure

If I add a condition before deploying a template for a virtual network I always get this error :If I remove the condition it works???

**template deployment returned the following errors:
Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/dm5DbServer' reference to 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/dm5VirtualNetwork' requires an API version.**

```
"resources": [
{
  "condition": "[equals(parameters('BuildDatabaseServer'), 'yes')]",
  "apiVersion": "2016-02-01",
  "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "dependsOn": [],
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "templateLink": {
      "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('virtualNetworkTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "virtualNetworkName": { "value": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]" },
      "vNetPrefix": { "value": "[variables('vNetPrefix')]" },
      "databaseSubnetPrimaryName": { "value": "[variables('databaseSubnetPrimaryName')]" },
      "databaseSubnetPrimaryPrefix": { "value": "[variables('databaseSubnetPrimaryPrefix')]" },
      "databaseSubnetPrimaryNsgName": { "value": "[variables('databaseSubnetPrimaryNsgName')]" }
    }
  }
},
```

Template being called:

```
  {
  "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('databaseSubnetPrimaryNsgName'))]",
  ],
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]"
  },
  "properties": {
    "addressSpace": {
      "addressPrefixes": [
        "[parameters('vNetPrefix')]"
      ]
    },
    "subnets": [

      {
        "name": "[parameters('databaseSubnetPrimaryName')]",
        "properties": {
          "addressPrefix": "[parameters('databaseSubnetPrimaryPrefix')]",
          "networkSecurityGroup": {
            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('databaseSubnetPrimaryNsgName'))]"
          }
        }
      }

  {
  "condition": "[equals(parameters('BuildDatabaseServer'), 'yes')]",
  "apiVersion": "2016-02-01",
  "name": "[variables('databaseServerName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "templateLink": {
      "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('commonTemplateArchiveFolder'), '/', variables('virtualMachineTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "serverName": { "value": "[variables('databaseServerName')]" },
      "adminUserName": { "value": "[variables('databaseServerAdminUserName')]" },
      "adminPassword": { "value": "[parameters('databaseServerAdminPassword')]" },
      "serverWindowsOSVersion": { "value": "[parameters('databaseServerWindowsOSVersion')]" },
      "serverVmSize": { "value": "[variables('databaseServerVmSize')]" },
      "primaryNetworkSecurityGroupName": { "value": "[variables('databaseSubnetPrimaryNsgName')]" },
      "primarySubnetRef": { "value": "[reference(variables('virtualNetworkName')).outputs.databaseSubnetPrimaryRef.value]" },
      "primaryPrivateIPAddress": { "value": "[variables('databaseServerPrimaryPrivateIPAddress')]" },
      "serverOsDiskStorageAccountType": { "value": "[variables('databaseServerOSDiskStorageAccountType')]" },
      "serverDataDiskStorageAccountType": { "value": "[variables('databaseServerDataDiskStorageAccountType')]" },
      "serverDataDiskSizeGB": { "value": "[variables('databaseServerDataDiskSizeGB')]" },
      "monitoringAgentWorkspaceID": { "value": "[parameters('monitoringAgentWorkspaceID')]" },
      "monitoringAgentWorkspaceKey": { "value": "[parameters('monitoringAgentWorkspaceKey')]" },
      "customscripts": { "value": "[variables('customScripts')]" }
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 12):

Ok so, judging by the error, you have another child deployment (`Microsoft.Resources/deployments/dm5DbServer`) in the same template and you are using a reference function to grab some data from that and it fails, because you are not providing the API versión it fails. [Check the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource?toc=%2fazure%2ftemplates%2ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Ftemplates%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json#reference) on this. If the resource you are referencing isnt being deployed in the same template you need to provide an api-versión to the reference function.

```
reference(xxx, '2017-01-01`)
```

Comment: ive added  Microsoft.Resources/deployments/dm5DbServer resource in the code above. which API resource do i need to change though?

Comment: can you upload both the templates to someplace where they are readable? like paste.ee or pastebin or something? its really hard to examine them like this?

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was deploying a resource with a condition. The deployment would fail with said error message when this condition was not met.

The reason for that was that I references the conditional resource somewhere else using the `reference(...)` statement. It seems that the reference calls are still evaluated even if the resource should not be deployed.

Adding a condition before the reference call fixed the issue:

`if({condition}, {original Statement}, 'resource not deployed')`

Comment: Wouldn't this say that it cannot find the resource named "resource not deployed" ??
If anything I would think you'd want an empty string there.

Answer (score 0):

Applying @DeveloperExceptionError answer, here is a bicep example using the `aks_enable_private_cluster` variable for conditional deployment:

```
// User Managed Identity
resource idAccessToAks 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2018-11-30' = if (aks_enable_private_cluster) {
  name: 'id_aks_access_n'
  location: resourceGroup().location
}

// User Managed Identity RBAC assignment
resource idAccessToAksRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-08-01-preview' = if (aks_enable_private_cluster) {
  name: guid(subscription().id, 'dev', '3498e952-d568-435e-9b2c-8d77e338d7f7')
  properties: {
    principalId: aks_enable_private_cluster ? idAccessToAks.properties.principalId : ''
    roleDefinitionId: '${subscription().id}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/3498e952-d568-435e-9b2c-8d77e338d7f7'
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
  }
}
```